# Pine Script: Draw hline of the lowest low in the last 10 bars

Tags: pine-script

I would like to get the lowest low of the last 10 bars in TradingView. I have tried this:

```
if(barstate.islast)
    bottom = lowest(10)
    hline(bottom)
```

But it gives me the error 'Cannot call hline with series[float]'. Since bottom is apparently a series, I've also tried referencing position 0 of bottom like this:

```
if(barstate.islast)
    bottom = lowest(10)
    hline(bottom[0])
```

This returns the same error. It still thinks I'm passing a series, but I am trying to pass a float. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I need to be able to do calculations on multiple bars and draw lines based on those calculations.

Answer (score 2):

This will plot what you're asking:

```
//@version=4
study("Line", overlay=true)

bars_back  = input(10)
draw_hline = input(true)

var line myLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend = draw_hline ? extend.both : extend.right, color=color.yellow, style=line.style_dashed, width=2)

ll = lowest(bars_back)
lb = lowestbars(bars_back) // returns a negative offset number

line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index + lb, ll)
line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index,      ll)
```

Example:

[image]